# DirectX 12 SDK LNK2001

Tags: c++, sdk, directx, directx-12, lnk2001

I keep getting this link error:

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol D3D12SerializeRootSignature
```

even though i have the SDK linked and added to C/C++ and VC++

Comment: What do you mean by "DirectX 12 SDK"? The [legacy DirectX SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directx-sdk--august-2009-) has no DX12 content, and all the DX12 content is found in the Windows 10 SDK.

Comment: they just wanted a title and they wouldnt let me choose anything else

Comment: What compiler & SDK are you using? If you are using Visual C++, you should take a look at [directx-vs-templates](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-vs-templates/wiki).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this line...

```
#pragma comment(lib,"d3d12.lib")
```

… in the include file to make sure that the d3d12.lib is visible to the linker.

Answer (score 1):

To people who use cmake this is the answer:

```
target_link_libraries(foo PRIVATE "d3d12.lib")
```

Not to disparage your answer at all. But personally I like describing build system aspects in the build system and not in the source code.

https://cmake.org/

EDIT:

Also with DX12 coming to Windows Subsystem for Linux this cmake answer is even more relevant:

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/directx/directx-heart-linux/